# An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=405) in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native

I have a React Native application and I am trying to run it on iOS Simulator.

My `Xcode version` is `13.0 (13A233)` and all my simulators have iOS 15.0 on them. Working on MacMini M1.

When i run `yarn ios` to run the app on iOS Simulator it throws the next error:

```
success Successfully built the app
--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:373C24F3-E3FC-46E3-AEFD-AE709B48A1A9, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 8 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:6E3EFB65-6333-47EB-9214-D260D237E418, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 8 Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:B706104A-02C8-4758-8F2B-BA1CD6C428A9, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:88A9D54B-3856-4688-BC25-56A00AB45F96, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:3432AE53-99BE-49FA-89CD-4C44A2D1851A, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:4D32F932-8462-4C77-AD0D-8F3866CE4CCF, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:AFA9EFB4-FF44-4445-AF16-378D030DD579, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:E420097E-48F9-4A09-A14F-4D244F0A45C9, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:FEB6F76D-91D0-4122-8C7B-0A67F9CA9D49, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 mini }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:81EA832E-6ED3-4560-8994-298CB8A00D2A, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:036436DB-1FA6-4DC5-BCA9-36BE0E55A42C, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:FDFD50F2-F5DA-428D-AAA5-A61220350314, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:8AAB66F9-2DAE-4DAD-BA51-2F3485BEA2F1, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 mini }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:DE213B2E-07EB-4E44-ABDC-55002D138527, OS:15.0, name:iPhone SE (2nd generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:09441BEE-CA99-4690-91C9-142DC592F01D, OS:15.0, name:iPod touch (7th generation) }
{ platform:macOS, arch:arm64, variant:Designed for [iPad,iPhone], id:A730556B-A531-5E09-93AB-53FE58E6CE75 }
{ platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:11D091C1-1B7C-4082-A40B-A36031EBE3E6, OS:15.0, name:iPad (9th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:8C1CDC41-42DC-4497-B58C-AF5E5E936404, OS:15.0, name:iPad Air (4th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:3FB7EC09-AE93-4DA0-AD1B-60BB6DB5145A, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:B879C8FC-D294-450F-9D87-DD8EF6E7EC7F, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:6A369D1C-4827-4098-8C1A-9D3D5B9826CE, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:F8530D4B-652E-4EB5-9DE6-88A780BAC754, OS:15.0, name:iPad mini (6th generation) }
info Installing "/Users/vladpopa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LocalHero-dcsfthvzgxjpjkbqzlsteoeipviz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/LocalHero.app"
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=405):
Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown
info Launching "org.name.LocalHeroClient"
error Failed to launch the app on simulator, An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=405):
Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown
```

The app is building but it won't open the simulator.

**The only way I found yet for that is to quit the simulator and open it manually. But how can I resolve this issue to open the simulator and work from the first time?**